# Docker entrypoint vs docker command and what's between them?

Tags: docker

While running a docker image named `bobo:net` with a python 3 script `service.py`:

```
docker run --entrypoint=python3 bobo:net service.py
```

Why is the image name specified in the middle of the actual command that is being ran?

Is the entrypoint only `python3`?

Why can't it simply be `python3 service.py`

What are the differences between entrypoint and command and what goes where?

Comment: ... because that's how docker run was designed?

Comment: @Paolo But what is the structure? I can't seem to find the accessible documentation tutorial or source code that explains this. python3 service.py is a valid Linux command. Obviously, python3 xyz service.py is not a valid command. What if tomorrow we need to run another command. What is the rule about where the docker image name goes?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/ the format is `docker run [OPTIONS] IMAGE [COMMAND] [ARG...]`

Comment: So why is it [COMM [IMAGE] AND] in this case?
Again: python3 service.py is a [COMMAND]
bobo:net is an [IMAGE]

Comment: It's not. `--entrypoint` is an option

Comment: Are entrypoints not commands? Normally, any entrypoint is simply something that can be ran in Linux.

Comment: `--entrypoint` is an option to docker run. So it has to come before the image name. Everything that comes to the image name is passed to the entrypoint

Comment: Also see [What is the difference between CMD and ENTRYPOINT in a Dockerfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile), though that doesn't discuss the `docker run` syntax.  You should not usually need `docker run --entrypoint` (with its awkward syntax) and if you find yourself needing it you might redesign your Dockerfile to put the actual command in a `CMD` rather than `ENTRYPOINT`.  Also consider tweaking your Python script so you don't need to name the `python3` interpreter explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to Paolo:

It appears that you are:

1. Limited to provide only one item in the `--entrypoint` option.
2. After all the options, such as entrypoint, you specify your `IMAGE` name
3. In the very end, you can specify arguments that are passed onto that `--entrypoint` option you specified

So essentially, if you want to run `koprulu` on `braxis`, with the docker image `star:craft`, you would type:

docker run --entrypoint=koprulu star:craft braxis

Comment: @Paolo, is this correct?